# Unwanted space beneath footer

Tags: html, css, browser, footer, space

When the browser window is stretched a certain height (seems to be on large screens), I'm getting some unwanted space beneath my footer.

It's only happening when there's not alot of content (height) on the page.

http://yyy.comuf.com/PORTV2/fold.php

I want the footer to stick to the bottom of the browser window at all times, but I don't want to use position:fixed;.

Comment: This is the solution I usually use: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;`

```
footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #343334;
    border-top: 7px solid #4D4D4F;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4000;
}
```

Comment: Neither solution working unfortunately! Still space underneath the footer when browser is stretched on a large screen.